# Nearest neighbour treatment of orthogonal vectors

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nearest-neighbor

When using nearest neighbours (scikit) on text classification, sometimes there is no similarity with any of the classes. When this happens, the scikit algorithm returns a distance of 1, and seems to choose a seemingly random class (it's the same within each running, but sometimes changes when running again). It would be helpful for when the vectors are orthogonal to return something specific like None.

```
    vec = CountVectorizer(strip_accents='ascii', stop_words = stopwords, ngram_range=(1, 3))
    bag_of_words = vec.fit_transform(list(map(str, Property))) #reference
    tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()
    X_train_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(bag_of_words.minimum(1))

    neigh = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors = neighbors) 
    neigh.fit(X_train_tfidf)

    X_test_counts = vec.transform(wines_strings).minimum(1)

    res = neigh.kneighbors(X_test_counts, return_distance = True)
```

Comment: What choice of algorithm did you use and can you share some of your code? The choice of neighbors search algorithm is controlled through the keyword 'algorithm', which must be one of ['auto', 'ball_tree', 'kd_tree', 'brute']. When the default value 'auto' is passed, the algorithm attempts to determine the best approach from the training data.

Comment: I added my code, but don't think it's going to be helpful in this situation. It's just the standard stuff.

Comment: I wonder if I change it to Brute whether that will result at least in the same class every time I run it, which can at least then be dealt with secondarily

Answer (score 0):

I decided to just add a calculation to determine if the vectors are orthogonal. When they are orthogonal, I disregard whatever Nearest Neighbours is spitting out

```
    a = X_train_tfidf@X_test_counts.transpose()
    indicator = a.transpose()*np.ones(a.get_shape()[0])
```